How do Docker user namespace really work?
I have enabled user namespaces in Docker, in an attempt to (I thought) any user used by any of the containers to a specific one.
This user has been created by docker, and the entries in subuid and subgid have been created:
dockremap:362144:65536

While dockremap itself has the id 116,
I'd expect now that I can bind any file from the host to the container and that, provided that the file is owned by dockremap on the host or the permissions are open enough, the container would be able to read it. The same with the directories.
Instead, I found myself having to make the owner of the files/folders by some user from 362144 on (which translates to nothing on the host, so ls, ps, etc.. just shows the numeric id).
Is this expected to work like this? Because I am doing it wrong or, from administration point of view, is a nightmare.

Yes, it's expected to work like this. The subuid file does not imply that anything will be mapped to your account – quite the opposite, it reserves a range of free 'real' UIDs for use by your containers specifically so that they do not overlap with real system accounts nor with containers run by other users.
Linux user namespace ID-mapping is always 1:1; a range can only be mapped to another range of the same size. This is because UID mapping must function in both directions – not only when assigning a real UID for newly created files, but also when determining what owner to display inside the container for existing files.
For example, given the 1:1 mapping you have, a file owned by the container's UID 1000 will be stored as having 363144 as its real owner, so that when the container is started again and the information retrieved, the host's 363144 can be translated back to the container's 1000.
If the mapping was not 1:1 (e.g. if all of the container UIDs were mapped to the same host UID) then information of which container user owns which container file would be lost. (The container owner could in theory be stored in xattrs, but Linux does not do so natively. I've heard that Docker does this on macOS using its own FUSE layer though, and I suspect that it might use fuse-overlayfs for this on Linux, but I've never worked with Docker to that extent so I don't know for sure.)
With recent Linux kernels, it is also possible to apply UID mappings to mounts, not only to user namespaces, so in theory the container engine could be told to bind-mount a directory into the container while mapping the container's UID 1000 to the host's UID 1000, or something like that. I've seen this option in systemd-nspawn, but again, I don't know where to find it in Docker – although documentation suggests that it would use shiftfs or fuse-overlayfs for this purpose, rather than native Linux idmapping.
